# ValueError: Transfer function is non-proper; can't convert to StateSpace system | control python library

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a microgrid model with the control python library. I'm using the microgrid model that were proposed by [Skiparev et al.][1] (see images below for the equations or look at equations 1, 2 and 3 in the paper)

The code below raises **ValueError: Transfer function is non-proper; can't convert to StateSpace system**.

I cannot find where the problem is.

````
system_list = []
------------------------------------------parameters----------------------------------------
T_PV = 1.5
T_WT = 1.85
K_VI = 1.2
T_VI = 0.1
H = 0.5
D = 1.5
KI = 0.05
T_g = 0.1
T_t = 0.4
R  = 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


delta_P_PV = ctrl.tf([1], [T_PV, 1], inputs='d_P_solar', outputs='delta_P_PV')
system_list.append(delta_P_PV)


delta_P_L = ctrl.summing_junction(inputs=['delta_P_RL', 'delta_P_IL'], outputs='delta_P_L')
system_list.append(delta_P_L)


delta_P_WT = ctrl.tf([1], [T_WT, 1], inputs='d_Pwind', outputs='delta_P_WT')
system_list.append(delta_P_WT


delta_P_inertia = ctrl.tf([K_VI], [1, T_VI], inputs='RoCoF', outputs='delta_P_inertia')
system_list.append(delta_P_inertia)

sum_inputs = ctrl.summing_junction(inputs=['delta_P_PV', '-delta_P_L', 'delta_P_WT', 'delta_P_WT', 'delta_P_inertia'], outputs='sum_inputs')
system_list.append(sum_inputs)

input_delta_f = ctrl.summing_junction(inputs=['sum_inputs', 'delta_P_m'], outputs='input_delta_f')
system_list.append(input_delta_f)

delta_f = ctrl.tf([1], [2*H, D], inputs='input_delta_f', outputs='delta_f')
system_list.append(delta_f)



delta_P_ACE = ctrl.tf([KI], [1, 0], inputs='delta_f', outputs='delta_P_ACE')
system_list.append(delta_P_ACE)

delta_f_R = ctrl.tf([0, 1], [0, R], inputs='delta_f', outputs='delta_f_R')
system_list.append(delta_f_R)

input_delta_Pg = ctrl.summing_junction(inputs=['-delta_f_R', 'delta_P_ACE'], outputs='input_delta_Pg')
system_list.append(input_delta_Pg)

delta_P_g = ctrl.tf([1], [T_g, 1], inputs='input_delta_Pg', outputs='delta_P_g')
system_list.append(delta_P_g)

delta_P_m = ctrl.tf([1], [T_t, 1], inputs='delta_P_g', outputs='delta_P_m')
system_list.append(delta_P_m)

RoCoF = ctrl.tf([1, 0], [1], inputs='delta_f', outputs='RoCoF')
system_list.append(RoCoF)


T = ctrl.interconnect(system_list, inputs=['d_P_solar', 'delta_P_RL', 'delta_P_IL', 'd_Pwind'],
                       outputs='delta_f')```


[system equations-1][2]
[system equations-2][3]
[system equations-3][4]


  [1]: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/344935359
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFHNL.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KbpA.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/44Wuj.png
````